# With AnyLogic, Can we compile Road Traffic Library and GIS map to simulate Supply Chain and Logistics for entire city?

Tags: javascript, gis, logistic-regression, anylogic, transport

I want to simulate the Supply Chain and Logistics for the entire city by using AnyLogic. Therefore, the simulation model should replicate the environmental system of the city logistic which has to simulate the external features of the city regarding the traffic congestion issue.  Typically, this system must include the roads, streets of the city, and vehicles should circulate more or less randomly in it in order to model the congestion issues. Is it possible to simulate that with Anylogic? Any suggestion on that?

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome to StackOverflow. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question if far too broad and more a discussion on "is it possible". Those are best posted on LinkedIn. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great SOF questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  :)

Comment: Hello Benjamin, Thank you very much for your suggestions and supports.